# Work with several Github repositories under one project

Tags: github, version-control, project-management, github-projects

In my team we have several related Github repositories and we want to use [Github project boards](https://help.github.com/articles/about-project-boards/) functionality. As I see, each specific project should be linked with some specific Github repository. But what if I want to have one Project for several repositories? Is there any possibility to set it up this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if your team is working from an organisation, you can set up a Project on it:

[image]

https://blog.github.com/2016-10-27-introducing-projects-for-organizations/.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the ability to have these to options has been removed from the "New" Projects, at least in the current beta form. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/52841